# ErrorException: Undefined variable: goals in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel

In my `Laravel-5.8 Controller`, I have this code:

```
public function selfReview()
{
    try {  
        $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;

        $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')
                        ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
                        ->where('is_current', 1)
                        ->first();              
        
        if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Employee')) {
            if(empty($identities)) {
                Session::flash('error', 'The current performance year has not been setup.');

                return redirect()->back();
            } else {
                $goals = Goal::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)
                            ->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->where('is_approved', 3)
                            ->where('is_visible', 1)
                            ->where('is_special_project', 0)
                            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                            ->get();
            } 
                       
            $incompleteCount = $goals->filter(function($item) {
                return ($item->line_manager_mid_year_approved == 0 || $item->line_manager_mid_year_approved == 2)
            })->count();                                        
        }   
        
        return view('selfReview')->with(['goals' => $goals, 'incompleteCount' => $incompleteCount]); 
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        Log::error($exception);
        Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');

        return back();
    }                     
}
```

When I wanted to render the blade, I got this error:

```
production.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined variable: goals
```

and it points at this line:

```
->with(['goals' => $goals, 'incompleteCount' => $incompleteCount]);
```

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `$goals` inside an if-else, if the `empty($identities)` pass the first if condition, `$goals` will not be declared. So you should declare him before the if-else:

```
$goals = []

if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Employee')) {
if(empty($identities)){
    Session::flash('error', 'The current performance year has not been setup.');
    return redirect()->back();
}else{
   $goals = Goal::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->where('is_approved', 3)->where('is_visible', 1)->where('is_special_project', 0)->whereNull('deleted_at')->get();
}                        
    $incompleteCount = $goals->filter(function($item) {
           return ($item->line_manager_mid_year_approved == 0 || $item->line_manager_mid_year_approved == 2);
      })->count();                                        
}  

return view('selfReview')
            ->with(['goals' => $goals, 'incompleteCount' => $incompleteCount]); 
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    Log::error($exception);
    Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
    return back();
    }
```

}
Also, try using the `compact()` method instead of `with()`

```
return view('selfReview', compact('goals', 'incompleteCount');
```